Keeping track of already visisted vertexes in sack
I want to make use of the sack to keep track of which vertexes have already been traversed and not continuing if the traverser encounters a vertex that is already in the list. The sack could keep a list of vertexes (either the vertex itself, or the vertex id or some other unique property like name in this case).
So here condensed to the absolute minimum: there is a starting vertex with name 'TS', it's put in the sack and then two edges are traversed, checking the reached vertex is not the starting vertex again. I tried to express it like this, but the returned paths always include path starting and ending at TS.
g.withSack([]){it.clone()}
    .V()
    .has('name', 'TS')
    .sack{a,v->a+=v.id()}
    .both()
    .both()
    .where(id().not(is(within(sack()))))
    .path().by('name')

Same in this example, expressing a little bit more what I intend to do
g.withSack([]){it.clone()}
    .V()
    .has('name', 'TS')
    .sack{a,v->a+=v.id()}
    .repeat(
        both()
        .where(id().not(is(within(sack()))))
        .sack{a,v->a+=v.id()}
    )
    .times(2)
    .path().by('name')

As a side note: I know about simplePath, but this is more about keeping track of some (not all) vertexes that have been visited already - because only some vertexes will go into the sack, not all of them.
Is my query wrong or is there some erroneous reasoning and the whole idea cannot work?

Sack isn't really meant to be used this way.  You're better off using something like aggregate() or store().
Example query here where I have a graph of movie artists (actors/actresses) and corresponding movies they performed in:
(Artist)<-(movie)->(Artist)
Say I wanted to find all movies that Kevin Bacon and actors up to two hops away also performed in, where the runtime of the movie was less than 45 minutes:
g.V().hasLabel('Artist').has('name','Kevin Bacon').
    repeat( 
        in('actor','actress').
        sideEffect(where(values('runtime').is(lte(45))).aggregate('shortshows')).
        out('actor','actress').simplePath()
    ).times(2).cap('shortshows').
    select('shortshows').unfold().dedup().valueMap()

Which returns:
1   {'title': ['The Big Green'], 'year': [2014], 'runtime': [32]}
2   {'title': ['Material of the Future'], 'year': [2014], 'runtime': [41]}
3   {'title': ['California Sea Lions'], 'year': [2004], 'runtime': [45]}
4   {'title': ['Sky Island'], 'year': [2010], 'averageRating': [7.4], 'numVotes': [47], 'runtime': [27]}
5   {'title': ['To the Arctic 3D'], 'year': [2012], 'averageRating': [6.6], 'numVotes': [1006], 'runtime': [40]}
6   {'title': ['The Man Who Built Cambodia'], 'year': [2017], 'averageRating': [8.9], 'numVotes': [9], 'runtime': [35]}
7   {'title': ['Hope in Heaven'], 'year': [2005], 'averageRating': [6.7], 'numVotes': [19], 'runtime': [45]}
8   {'title': ['Herschel Hopper: New York Rabbit'], 'year': [2000], 'averageRating': [6.8], 'numVotes': [19], 'runtime': [45]}
9   {'title': ['In the Night I Remember Your Name'], 'year': [2018], 'runtime': [44]}
10  {'title': ['Stuart Davis: In Full Swing'], 'year': [2017], 'runtime': [30]}

The aggregate() allows me to collect the results as I go. The sideEffect() allows me to do this and not filter out paths in the traversal along the way.  cap() ensures that all of the traversals collapse back to a single traversal before then fetching the results from the aggreagate (which will be stored in a list), unfolding the list, deduping the results, and displaying all of their properties.
You don't need all that lambda-mumbo-jumbo. ;)
